# Microsoft Edge's default tracker prevention mode prevents connection of Firebase in Next.js App

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, microsoft-edge

On the Next.js side, I installed the installations through Google's documentation on Firebase without any problems. While it works perfectly in all browsers, there is a problem in the sign-in phase in Microsoft Edge.

[image: Console Logs]

When I turn off the switch named "Tracking prevention for this site (Balanced)" in the screenshot, there is no problem accessing the Firebase auth.

[image]

Comment: Hi Berk, I saw you requested an edit to my answer. I'm wondering if my answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, to prevent this issue, you should add your project's URL to **edge://settings/privacy/trackingPreventionExceptions**
[image]

As to why this is showing only in Microsoft Edge, tracking prevention is a feature in Microsoft Edge protects users from online tracking by restricting the ability of trackers to access browser-based storage as well as the network.

Referring to [Determining whether/how a particular URL is classified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/tracking-prevention#determining-whetherhow-a-particular-url-is-classified), you will find `gstatic.com` and `google.com` listed in the [Disconnect services.json list](https://github.com/disconnectme/disconnect-tracking-protection/blob/master/services.json), which means they are classfied trackers, and you are expected to see the warning in the console.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My problem is not to solve it personally, but to make sure that anyone who wants to access this product I have developed can access the project without modifiyng with their browser settings. In other words, what should I do on the code side so that they are not affected by this restriction?

Comment: @BerkŞENGÜL Are the functionalities affected by these warnings? Normally, tracking prevention won't affect the functionalities, only presenting some warning messages in the console.

Comment: Yes, these tracking preventions prevent the user from logging into the system via Firebase/auth. This problem does not occur in other browsers.

Comment: @BerkŞENGÜL Are you using signInWithRedirect? You can check this doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices

Comment: Hello, I am only using signInAnonymously. I will review the document you sent.

Comment: @BerkŞENGÜL Just to check, have you got anything from the document?

Comment: I realized that the method currently used is signInAnonymously() so that doc is not related with my problem. When I investigated this problem in more detail, I found that the problem is related to the browser blocking the recaptcha. So the problem is not with Firebase, but with Google ReCaptcha.